# How to read GIF with alpha channel in python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, gif

As title described, how to read GIF file with alpha channel in python opencv? I used following code, but it shows black background in transparent area, and it shows the frame only contains 3 channels.

```
gif = cv2.VideoCapture('fire.gif')
while True:
  success, frame = gif .read()
  if success:
    print(frame.shape)
    cv2.imshow("git", frame)
    ...
```

Solution:

1. I don't know why opencv could not read out the alpha channel of the gif?
2. Finally I turned to use imageio instead

```
gif_reader = imageio.get_reader('fire.gif')
gif_length = gif_reader.get_length()
frame_index = 0
while True:
    if frame_index < gif_length:
        frame = gif_reader.get_data(frame_index)
        frame_index = frame_index + 1
        print(frame.shape)
        cv2.imshow("gif", frame)
        ...
```

Comment: A GIF doesn't have an alpha channel, ever.  It simply has one color out of the 256 possible designated as the transparent color.

Comment: And the `cv2.imshow` window has a black background, so even if a pixel were transparent, it would show up black.

Comment: Thank you guys, finally I turned to use imageio instead, and this could read the alpha channel